# SDK - R18 still has some bug

Tags: android, arcgis

Some jar libraries in the libs/ folder are not picked up in some cases.
Just like arcgis for Android sample project "HelloWord", compiled without problems, but can't run properly.

```
04-16 14:56:33.104: D/dalvikvm(9369): Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-16 14:56:33.134: I/dalvikvm(9369): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 7...
04-16 14:56:33.234: D/ArcGIS.LifeCycle(9369): map.onChildViewAdded
04-16 14:56:33.244: D/ArcGIS.LifeCycle(9369): map.initLayer
04-16 14:56:33.244: D/ArcGIS.LifeCycle(9369): >>>layer init startcom.esri.android.map.ags.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer
04-16 14:56:33.244: D/ArcGIS.LifeCycle(9369): layer init...
04-16 14:56:33.244: W/dalvikvm(9369): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode;)
04-16 14:56:33.244: I/dalvikvm(9369): Could not find method org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode.get, referenced from method com.esri.android.a.e.a
04-16 14:56:33.244: W/dalvikvm(9369): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4781: Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode;.get (Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode;
04-16 14:56:33.244: D/dalvikvm(9369): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0005
04-16 14:56:33.244: I/dalvikvm(9369): Could not find method 
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode.getTextValue, referenced from method com.esri.android.a.e.a
04-16 14:56:33.244: W/dalvikvm(9369): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4784:  Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode;.getTextValue ()Ljava/lang/String;
04-16 14:56:33.244: D/dalvikvm(9369): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
04-16 14:56:33.244: E/HtcAppUsageStatsListener(9369): afterPerformResume
04-16 14:56:33.244: E/HtcAppUsageStatsListener(9369): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 14:56:33.244: E/HtcAppUsageStatsListener(9369):   at android.app.HtcAppUsageStatsListener.afterPerformResume(HtcAppUsageStatsListener.java:77)
04-16 14:56:33.244: D/ArcGIS.TileCache(9369): max number of cached tiles:1000
04-16 14:56:33.244: D/ArcGIS.LifeCycle(9369): sdcache inited.
04-16 14:56:33.244: D/ArcGIS.TileCache(9369): SDCardCache
04-16 14:56:33.244: E/dalvikvm(9369): Could not find class 
'org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory', referenced from method com.esri.core.internal.b.a.e.<clinit>
04-16 14:56:33.244: W/dalvikvm(9369): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 717 
(Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory;) in Lcom/esri/core/internal/b/a/e;
04-16 14:56:33.244: D/dalvikvm(9369): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
04-16 14:56:33.244: W/dalvikvm(9369): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory;)
04-16 14:56:33.254: I/dalvikvm(9369): Could not find method org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory.createJsonParser, referenced from method com.esri.core.internal.b.a.e.a
04-16 14:56:33.254: W/dalvikvm(9369): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4760:   Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory;.createJsonParser 
(Ljava/io/InputStream;)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonParser;
04-16 14:56:33.254: D/dalvikvm(9369): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x016c
04-16 14:56:33.254: I/dalvikvm(9369): Could not find method org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory.createJsonParser, referenced from method com.esri.core.internal.b.a.e.a
04-16 14:56:33.254: W/dalvikvm(9369): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4761: Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory;.createJsonParser (Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonParser;
04-16 14:56:33.254: D/dalvikvm(9369): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0022
04-16 14:56:33.254: I/dalvikvm(9369): Could not find method org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory.createJsonParser, referenced from method com.esri.core.internal.b.a.e.a
04-16 14:56:33.254: W/dalvikvm(9369): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4761:     
Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory;.createJsonParser (Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonParser;
04-16 14:56:33.254: D/dalvikvm(9369): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001f
04-16 14:56:33.254: D/dalvikvm(9369): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x1296 at 0x02 in Lcom/esri/core/internal/b/a/e;.<clinit>
04-16 14:56:33.264: W/dalvikvm(9369): Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing Lcom/esri/core/internal/b/a/e;
04-16 14:56:33.274: D/ArcGIS(9369): Failed to initialize the MapView.
04-16 14:56:33.274: D/ArcGIS(9369): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-16 14:56:33.274: D/ArcGIS(9369):     at com.esri.core.internal.a.a.k.a(Unknown Source)
04-16 14:56:33.274: D/ArcGIS(9369):     at com.esri.android.map.ags.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer.initModel(Unknown Source)
04-16 14:56:33.274: D/ArcGIS(9369):     at com.esri.android.map.ags.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer.initModel(Unknown Source)
04-16 14:56:33.274: D/ArcGIS(9369):     at com.esri.android.map.LayerView.initLayer(Unknown Source)
04-16 14:56:33.274: D/ArcGIS(9369):     at com.esri.android.map.MapView$1.a(Unknown Source)
04-16 14:56:33.274: D/ArcGIS(9369):     at com.esri.android.map.MapView$1.call(Unknown Source)
04-16 14:56:33.274: D/ArcGIS(9369):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-16 14:56:33.274: D/ArcGIS(9369):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-16 14:56:33.274: D/ArcGIS(9369):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-16 14:56:33.274: D/ArcGIS(9369):     at         java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-16 14:56:33.274: D/ArcGIS(9369):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
04-16 14:56:33.274: D/ArcGIS(9369): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:         org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory
04-16 14:56:33.274: D/ArcGIS(9369):     at com.esri.core.internal.b.a.e.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
04-16 14:56:33.274: D/ArcGIS(9369):     ... 11 more
04-16 14:56:33.274: D/ArcGIS.LifeCycle(9369): sdcard inited.
04-16 14:56:33.294: D/ArcGIS.LifeCycle(9369): map.onSizechanged
04-16 14:56:33.294: D/ArcGIS.LifeCycle(9369): !!! onSizeChangedSignal
04-16 14:56:33.294: D/ArcGIS.LifeCycle(9369): map.onLayout
04-16 14:56:33.304: D/ArcGIS.LifeCycle(9369): map.onLayout
04-16 14:56:33.314: D/memalloc(9369): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51fbc000 size:27017216 offset:24928256 fd:56
```

Answer (score 0):

we might have encountered the same [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340604/is-ant-1-8-used-with-androids-sdk-buildafter-tools-revision-17-buged) - In my case the solution was to separate the Ant targets to two calls (i.e. "ant myParameters myTarget1 myTarget2", and "ant myParameters debug delivery"). Hope this works for you, anyhow - Google need to add better support for their undocumented/faulty changes (and stackoverflow isn't the best place for questions that are not originated in stupidity, as the lifetime of a complex question isn't too long here).

If that doesn't work for you please elaborate your question.